# Javascript inside php not working

Tags: javascript, php

I've create a code that check if a variable is empty or not.
If the variable is empty I execute a javascript alert, in particular:

```
if($verbo_name == NULL)
{
    echo "
    <script>
        alert('no record available in the database');
    </script>";
    exit();
}
```

If I insert a message inside the `echo`, the message appears correctly, but I want show the alert in javascript. What's the error? Thanks..

UPDATE more details:

```
$results = $con->query("SELECT verbo, descrizione FROM verbo WHERE verbo = '$verbo'");

$verbo_name  = NULL; 

while($row = $results->fetch_array()) 
{
    $verbo_name = $row['verbo'];
}
```

Comment: is `$verbo_name` really `null`?

Comment: its working fine,make sure $verbo_name having null.

Comment: The error is that the alert doesn't appears. Anyway, all the solution posted not working for me..

Comment: Do a `var_dump($verbo_name);` before your if-statement and discover that the value in fact does not equal `NULL`.

Comment: Where does `$verbo_name` come from

Comment: I already executed a var_dump and this return me NULL in the page

Comment: I've added other details

Comment: If you're using AJAX, supply the relevant JS in your question. This might explain things.

Answer (score 0):

Check below codes are working fine for me.

```
<?php
    $verbo_name = NULL;
    if(is_null($verbo_name))
    {
        echo "
        <script>
            alert('no record available in the database');
        </script>";
        exit();
    }   
?>
```

Comment: `$verbo_name == null` was fine anyway, though

Comment: Yes that is fine,That is also working inside the if().But before that you have to assign a value to $verbo_name = "";It is advisble to use is_null() rather comparing with NULL.

Comment: <?php
 $verbo_name = "";
 if($verbo_name == NULL)
 {
  echo "
  <script>
   alert('no record available in the database');
  </script>";
  exit();
 }   
?>
It is also working for me.

Comment: Before using $verbo_name,You have to assign some value.If that value is NULL then the If part of the code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
if(empty($verbo_name))
{
    echo "
    <script>
        alert('no record available in the database');
    </script>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should trigger an alert:

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <?php
   if($verbo_name == NULL)
   {

    $msg = enter code here'no record available in the database';

   }  else {
   $msg = 'not set';
   }

   echo "
   <script>
   alert('". $msg ."');
   </script>";

   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

If the message is `not set` the problem is just the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is Pravat Kumar Sahoo's answer,
This must work fine.

If you are testing on google chrome, you might have prevented the alert dialog message mistakenly. Please try clearing the cache/cookie or test on any other browser.

```
<?php
$verbo_name = NULL;
if(is_null($verbo_name))
{
    echo "<script>alert('no record available in the database');</script>";
    exit();
}   
?>
```

Update:
Instead of alerting the message inside PHP, echo a message, like "NoData". And in the ajax calling Javascript, receive response "success".

```
echo "NoData"; // In PHP file.
```

In your Javascript, get the response,

```
 success:function(response)
 {
    if(response == "NoData");
    {
       alert("No data in the Database");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try my updated answer. That might do what you wanted.